# Firestore pagination using MVVM architecture swift

Tags: swift, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong since I am very new to MVVM. It worked in MVC architecture. I've setup my VM and am able to get the first set of results and even then that's not working properly. I get 4 results instead of 10 which is what LOADLIMIT is set as. I was able to get it to work in an MVC architecture without any issues. The VM function which triggers the query is called multiple (3) times instead of just once i.e. even prior to scrolling.

Here is my VM:

```
enum FetchRestaurant {
    case success
    case error
    case location
    case end
}
class ListViewModel {
    
    let restaurant: [Restaurant]?
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()
    var lastDocument: DocumentSnapshot?
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    
    typealias fetchRestaurantCallback = (_ restaurants: [Restaurant]?, _ message: String?, _ status: FetchRestaurant) -> Void
    var restaurantFetched: fetchRestaurantCallback?
    
    var fetchRestaurant: FetchRestaurant?
    
    init(restaurant: [Restaurant]) {
        self.restaurant = restaurant
    }
    
    func fetchRestaurantCallback (callback: @escaping fetchRestaurantCallback) {
        self.restaurantFetched = callback
    }
    
    func fetchRestaurants(address: String) {
        print("address received: \(address)")
        getLocation(from: address) { location in
            if let location = location {
                self.currentLocation = location
                self.queryGenerator(at: location)
            } else {
                self.restaurantFetched?(nil, nil, .location)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func queryGenerator(at location: CLLocation) {
        var query: Query!
if restaurantArray.isEmpty {
            query = db.collection("Restaurant_Data").whereField("distributionType", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 2).limit(to: Constants.Mealplan.LOADLIMIT)
        } else {
            print("last document:\(String(describing: lastDocument?.documentID))")
            query = db.collection("Restaurant_Data").whereField("distributionType", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 2).start(afterDocument: lastDocument!).limit(to: Constants.Mealplan.LOADLIMIT)
        }
        batchFetch(query: query)
    }
    
    func batchFetch(query: Query) {
        query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.restaurantFetched?(nil, error.localizedDescription, .error)
            } else if querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
self.restaurantFetched?(nil, nil, .end)
            } else if !querySnapshot!.isEmpty {
                let queriedRestaurants = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { querySnapshot -> Restaurant? in
                    return try? querySnapshot.data(as: Restaurant.self)
                }
                guard let restaurants = queriedRestaurants,
                  let currentLocation = self.currentLocation else {
                self.restaurantFetched?(nil, nil, .end)
                return }
                self.restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: self.applicableRestaurants(allQueriedRestaurants: restaurants, location: currentLocation))
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: {
                    self.restaurantFetched?(self.restaurantArray, nil, .success)
                })
                self.lastDocument = querySnapshot!.documents.last
            }
        }
    }

    func getLocation(from address: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ location: CLLocation?) -> Void) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location = placemarks.first?.location else {
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }
            completionHandler(location)
        }
    }

}
```

And in the VC viewDidLoad:

```
var fetchMore = false
var reachedEnd = false
let leadingScreensForBatching: CGFloat = 5.0
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var currentAddress : String?

var listViewModel = ListViewModel(restaurant: [Restaurant]())
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        listViewModel.fetchRestaurantCallback { (restaurants, error, result) in
            switch result {
            
            case .success :
                self.loadingShimmer.stopShimmering()
                self.loadingShimmer.removeFromSuperview()
                guard let fetchedRestaurants = restaurants else { return }
                self.restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: fetchedRestaurants)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.fetchMore = false
                
            case .location :
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "No businesses nearby", message: "Try going back and changing the address")
                
  

      case .error :
            guard let error = error else { return }
            self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Error", message: error)
            
        case .end :
            self.fetchMore = false
            self.reachedEnd = true
        }
    }
    
    if let currentAddress = currentAddress {
        listViewModel.fetchRestaurants(address: currentAddress)
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate links or resources for implementing MVVM in Swift for a Firestore back-end. I'm coming up short on searches here and on Google. Even tried medium.

*EDIT*

```
class ListViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    lazy var loadingShimmer: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "shimmer_background")
        let imageview = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageview.contentMode = .top
        imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageview
    }()
    
    var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()
    var planDictionary = [String: Any]()
    
    var fetchMore = false
    var reachedEnd = false
    let leadingScreensForBatching: CGFloat = 5.0
    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var currentAddress : String?
    
    var listViewModel = ListViewModel(restaurant: [Restaurant]())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTable()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    }
    
    func setupTable() {
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Restaurant", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        tableView.register(RestaurantCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -navigationBarHeight, right: 0)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        tableView.addSubview(loadingShimmer)
        loadingShimmer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        loadingShimmer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        loadingShimmer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        loadingShimmer.startShimmering()
        
        initialSetup()
    }
    
    func initialSetup() {
        let addressOne = planDictionary["addressOne"] as! String + ", "
        let city = planDictionary["city"] as! String + ", "
        let postalCode = planDictionary["postalCode"] as! String
        currentAddress = addressOne + city + postalCode
        
        setupSearch()

listViewModel.fetchRestaurantCallback { (restaurants, error, result) in
            switch result {
            
            case .success :
                self.loadingShimmer.stopShimmering()
                self.loadingShimmer.removeFromSuperview()
                guard let fetchedRestaurants = restaurants else { return }
                self.restaurantArray.append(contentsOf: fetchedRestaurants)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.fetchMore = false
                
            case .location :
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "No businesses nearby", message: "Try going back and changing the address")
                
            case .error :
                guard let error = error else { return }
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Error", message: error)
                
            case .end :
                self.fetchMore = false
                self.reachedEnd = true
            }
        }
        
        if let currentAddress = currentAddress {
            listViewModel.fetchRestaurants(address: currentAddress)
        }
   }

    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let off = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let off1 = scrollView.contentSize.height

        if off > off1 - scrollView.frame.height * leadingScreensForBatching {
            print("\(fetchMore), \(reachedEnd)")
            if !fetchMore && !reachedEnd {
                if let address = self.currentAddress {
                    print("address sent: \(address)")
                    listViewModel.fetchRestaurants(address: address)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A general advice, the M in MVVM stands for Model but is also for service and repository classes etc and I think you should use that by moving your firebase code out of the view model and into its own class (or struct) to separate. concerns

Comment: Good point. That said, I have been doing that after I get the VM, Controller and Views to pass the necessary acceptance tests.

Comment: As a side note, I think it was one of the founders of MVVM who said the architecture is overkill for most applications, definitely for simple ones like iOS apps. AFAIK, it was designed specifically for something they were working on at Microsoft. What I know for certain is that iOS documentation is almost entirely MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That you're only getting back 4 results instead of 10 is not due to a faulty query or get-document request—those are coded properly. You're either losing documents when you parse them (some are failing `Restaurant` initialization), `Constants.Mealplan.LOADLIMIT` is wrong, or there aren't more than 4 documents in the collection itself that satisfy the query.
2. That the query is executed 3 times instead of once is also not due to anything in this code—`viewDidLoad` is only called once and `geocodeAddressString` only returns once. You're making a fetch request elsewhere that we can't see.
3. In the `batchFetch` method, you have a guard that returns out of the function without ever calling its completion handler. This will leave the UI in a state of limbo. I'd recommend always calling the completion handler no matter why the function returns.
4. You never manage the document cursor. If the get-document return has less documents than the load limit, then nil the last-document cursor. This way, when you attempt to get the next page of documents, guard against a nil cursor and see if there is even more to fetch.
5. There's no need to pass in an empty array and have your function fill it; simply construct and return an array of results within `ListViewModel` itself.
6. We can't see how you trigger pagination. Is it through a scroll delegate when the user reaches the bottom or through a button tap, for example? If it's through a scroll delegate, then I'd disable that for now and see how many returns you get—I suspect one, instead of 3.

What is the particular reason you've ditched MVC for MVVM here? With MVC, you can get pagination up with just a few lines of code. I think MVVM is overkill for iOS applications and would advise against using it unless you have a compelling reason.

Comment: Thank you first of for the detailed response. Here are some comments:
1. Based on your feedback, I was able to debug and resolve it.
2. It's caused by the scrollview function which I added in my edit above. What's interesting is that I had this in the MVC as well and it was just called once.
3. I sort of understand what you are saying so I updated that block with the completion handler as indicated above
4. I don't quite understand this. Why would I nil the last document cursor is docs < LIMIT?
5. I tried that before but didn't help. Will try again with the other updates.
6. Done

Comment: The reason for MVC to MVVM is because the VC is already large. I need to switch from TableView to CollectionView and it's already at 300+ lines of code. Just as importantly, I would like to learn MVVC in (relatively) complex cases like pagination.

Comment: I've seen that 300-line rule tossed around a lot on the internet and IMO it's a completely arbitrary and meaningless number. Why 300? Why not 200? Why not 173? A view controller with lots of UI objects and delegates is going to consume lines. This has become a hill that fools are willing to die on. There is no inherent advantage in taking a single object with 1,000 lines of code and breaking them up into 4 objects each with 250 lines of code. You've met the arbitrary 300-line rule but now you've violated my arbitrary 3-object rule. You now have 4 times the objects and haven't saved any memory.

Comment: But if this is just a learning exercise then I have no problem with what you're doing. Otherwise, you've taken something idiomatic and made it idiosyncratic. Were you able to reduce the calls from 3 to 1 after removing the pagination triggers in the scroll delegate?

Comment: Got it. Yes, I do want to learn and get my understanding of MVVC to a point where I can do everything with it that I can with MVC. That said, no I am still getting 3 calls. I have verified that it's caused by the scrollView override function (posted above) and I have no idea why. It didn't call the same function to query for more data when I used it in the MVC archicture.

Comment: I refactored the scrollView func and now it's being called only once. I added the updated scrollView override. However, I am no longer getting the next batch of data and I am guessing it has something to do with your point no. 4 above but I am not sure how to handle it.

Comment: I figured out how to handle point #4. It's working as desired.